# Globals across modules

Tags: python

Wow, this seems so basic, but I can't get it to work. All I need to do is store a global dict which can be accessed and modified from other modules & threads.

What's the "best practices" way of achieving this?

test.py

```
import testmodule

class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global classa_dict
    classa_dict = {}
    classa_dict[1] = MyClassA(1)
    classa_dict[2] = MyClassA(2)

    testing = testmodule.TestModule()
```

testmodule.py

```
class TestModule():
    def __init__(self):
        global classa_dict
        print classa_dict[2]
```

output

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    testing = testmodule.TestModule()
  File "/path/to/project/testmodule.py", line 4, in __init__
    print classa_dict[2]
NameError: global name 'classa_dict' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact acchieve something like what you want:

testmodule.py:

```
classa_dict={}

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        global classa_dict
        print classa_dict[2]
```

test.py:

```
import testmodule

class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lclassa_dict = testmodule.classa_dict
    lclassa_dict[1] = MyClassA(1)
    lclassa_dict[2] = MyClassA(2)

    testing = testmodule.Test()
```

Please note that global is used somewhat else than what you might think of. If you write `global varname`, this means, that Python should not generate a *local* variable `varname`, but look in the global scope for a variable named `varname`. That is, the class `Test` does not generate a local variable `classa_dict`, but it uses the global variably `classa_dict` instead.

So, `global` is nothing to give at declaration to tell python that the variable can be used everywhere. It much more tells Python that there is already some variable with this name, that is referred to.

This means, in `testmodule.ty` the line `global classa_dict` means: Look somewhere in the module to find a variable `classa_dict` and operate on this variabla instead of creating a new *local* variable `classa_dict`.

In `test.py`, then you can assign `classa_dict = testmodule.classa_dict` which tells python that `lclassa_dict` refers to the `classa_dict` in `testmodule.py`. Therefore, you don't need a `global` in `test.py`, because, you simply modify `testmodule.classa_dict` when you assign something to `lclassa_dict`. Then, the class `Test` in `testmodule.py` knows that it should look to `testmodule.classa_dict` because it uses the `global`.

Comment: If ClassA had a method defined, should I be able to call that method from another thread when referencing it from the dict object?  I can access properties fine, but I'm having a hard time triggering methods that way.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is not to do this at all.

The `global` keyword is really misnamed - it just means module scope, rather than local. There's no way to have a variable that's in every scope automatically. Instead, define it at the module level in one module and import it wherever you need it.

Comment: An *evil*, *lazy* programmer might assign to the `__builtins__` module.